# Unity's text mesh pro input field caret is too wide and pushes text outside of textarea

Tags: unity-game-engine, caret

I'm working on a mind map editor in which the user can draw boxes and write text in them. However, the TMPro input fields I'm using in those boxes have extra-wide caret when I type in them, and changing the fonts didn't solve the problem. Here are some images of the issue:
[image]
The caret is so wide that it can push the text inside out of the box:
[image]
I tried to lower the caret width in my script, but it's an `int` and has already been set to 1. Can you give me some possible reasons as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem by multiplying width+height of my inputfield by 100 and dividing its scale by 100.
Don't forget to increase the font size significantly.